# Actions Buttons Not Showing in Local Notification

Tags: ios, swift

I am working with local notification in swift.when I execute the code I do not get Actions like  ACCEPT_IDENTIFIER and NOT_NOW_IDENTIFIER..on notification bar..I am using iOS sdk 8.4

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions   launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let notificationSettings : UIUserNotificationSettings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()

    if notificationSettings.types == UIUserNotificationType.None
    {
        var notificationTypes : UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Badge

        let notificationAction1:UIMutableUserNotificationAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
        notificationAction1.identifier = "ACCEPT_IDENTIFIER"
        notificationAction1.title = "Ok"
        notificationAction1.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Foreground
        notificationAction1.destructive = true
        notificationAction1.authenticationRequired = false

        let notificationAction2:UIMutableUserNotificationAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
        notificationAction2.identifier = "NOT_NOW_IDENTIFIER"
        notificationAction2.title = "No"
        notificationAction2.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
        notificationAction2.destructive = false
        notificationAction2.authenticationRequired = false


        let actionArrayDefault = NSArray(objects: notificationAction1,notificationAction2)
        let actionArrayMinimal = NSArray(objects: notificationAction1)

        var actionDemoCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
        actionDemoCategory.identifier = "ActionDemoCategory"
        actionDemoCategory.setActions(actionArrayDefault as [AnyObject], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)
        actionDemoCategory.setActions(actionArrayMinimal as [AnyObject], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)

        let categoryForSettings = NSSet(objects: actionDemoCategory)

        let newNotificationSetting = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: categoryForSettings as Set<NSObject>)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(newNotificationSetting)

    }

    return true
}
```

this code i written into viewDidLoad() method

```
 var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.alertBody = "Testing Notification"
    localNotification.alertAction = "Open It"
    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10)
    localNotification.category = "ActionDemoCategory"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

remove this

`if notificationSettings.types == UIUserNotificationType.None`

Comment: thanks.. now i am stuck at comparing two double values in swift..how can we compare two double values.

Comment: try `if a-b < 0.0001`, means a==b for Double